# User defined PK on yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am currently following the Yii2 start guide.

I am stumpted at the interacting with a database step.

I have created a database as they suggest with code as its primary key

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `code` CHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` CHAR(52) NOT NULL,
 `population` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I create a model and the CRUD methods using the gii generator.

The issue is that the generated code refers to id as a primary key at all times, not the case due to the suggested table structure, and even the findModel needs to be updated from.

```
 protected function findModel($code)
 {
    if (($model = Country2::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
}
```

To

```
 protected function findModel($code)
 {
    if (($model = Country2::findOne($code)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
}
```

Once updated the code works but the issue is with the gridview where every action has an id tacked on to it.

ie https://localhost/tutorialYii/web/index.php?r=country2%2Fview&id=12
rather than https://localhost/tutorialYii/web/index.php?r=country2%2Fview&code=12

I understand this can be fixed by using id as the primary key but I would like to understand how to address the issue of using a custom primary key rather than the standard one.

I have not modified the autogenerated code in any form.
The autogenerated code works for country2 which has id as its PK.  I would like to understand how to adapt it so that it works for a PK that is not id.

Comment: It looks like a bug in https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii - I suggest to report it.

Comment: It looks like this issue was introduced in gii 2.2.3. You can set your composer.json to require version 2.2.2. It will still name the param as `id` in url, but generated actions and `findModel()` method will expect it as `$id`, so it will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Implement `primarykey()` in your model:

```php
public static function primaryKey()
{
    return ['code'];
}
```

Now you can use this:

```php
YourModel::findOne($code);
```

and always use `$model->getPrimarykey()` instead `$model->code` for access to your primary key.